# how to use boost in solr?

Tags: angularjs, solr, solr-boost

I am new to solr and i have indexed fields like indiansPrefer and users i am firing a http request to get the response from solr with boost options

```
angular.element.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/food/select",
                data: {
                    "q": $scope.searchString,
                    "wt": "json",
                    "bq": "indiansPrefer:1^800",
                    "bq": "users:ak@mailinator.com^1000"
                    "start":0,
                    "rows":25

                },
                traditional: true,
                cache: true,
                async: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (data) {

                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.foodResults = data.response.docs;
                        console.log("result from solr is  ",$scope.foodResults)
                        /*angular.forEach($scope.foodResults,function(value,key){

                        });*/

                    });
                },
                jsonp: 'json.wrf'
            });
```

when i search for "burger" added by user ak which is indian preferred i am getting that doc first good. but when i search for a term "french" frenchfries which don't have a users field in it but indiansprefer as 1 should be coming up first.but i am getting burger as first item how to correct it.??

Comment: you can supply you data and sort after data so that we look it clearly

Answer (score 0):

Found the way it was the issue with giving the bq as to different parameters it has to be a single parameter

```
bq:"indiansPrefer:1^800 users:ak@mailinator.com^1000"
```